# Reactive form Angular breaks when updating an ArrayForm

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem using a reactive form in an Angular app.
I managed to isolate the problem in a Plunkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/KiTHcaaZZA6kwDI0sfeR?p=preview

What I have is a form with an ArrayForm section where I can add rows with a button.
Every one of these rows has many input fields, and a few of them display the result of other fields.
For example, in my plunkr I have a MAX and a MIN button, which are numbers, and when both of them have a value, I need to update the value of another field, called TOTAL.

So this is the html template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
  <input type="text" formControlName="client" placeholder="client">
  </div>

  <button type="button" (click)="addPublisher()">Add Publisher</button>

  <div formArrayName="publishers">
    <div *ngFor="let item of publishers; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input type="number" formControlName="max" placeholder="max">
        <input type="number" formControlName="min" placeholder="min">
        <input type="text" formControlName="total" placeholder="total">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

And this is the ts that matters. I'm subscribing to changes in the publishers, and updating the row only if the change is other than a row being added or deleted.

```
ngOnInit() {
    (this.form.get('publishers') as FormArray).valueChanges
      .map((publishers: any[]) => {
        if (this.totalPublishers === publishers.length) {
          publishers.forEach((publisher, index) => {
            console.log(`update publishers ${index}`);
            this.updatePublisher((this.form.get('publishers') as FormArray).get([index]) as FormGroup);
          });
        } else {
          console.log(`update total from ${this.totalPublishers} to ${publishers.length}`);
          this.totalPublishers = publishers.length;
        }
      })
      .subscribe();
  }
```

And to update the value, I do this

```
private updatePublisher(publisher: FormGroup) {
    this.updateTotals(publisher);
  }

  private updateTotals(publisher: FormGroup) {
    const max = publisher.get('max').value;
    const min = publisher.get('min').value;
    if (max && min) {
      console.log(max, min);
      const total = max - min;
      publisher.get('total').setValue(total);
    }
  }
```

If I execute this, when I update the first field (max) it checks the value, and as min does not exist yet, nothing happens. Correct.
Then when I edit the second value (min), this updateTotals is executed a zillion times, total is calculated at the end and updated in the field, but then if I try to edit those fields again and update the values nothing happens.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your expectation. Currently your facing issue because `addPublisher() method has only the min, max,total` as the form controls

Comment: if you test the plunkr you will see that the total is calculated the first time, although the updateTotals is executed and awful load of times, and then is like the subscribe is cancelled or something because when you try to update MIN or MAX then TOTAL is not updated any more and updateTotals is not executed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setValue` `valueChange` event is fired within `updateValueAndValidity`. One option should help you

```
publisher.get('total').setValue(total, { emitEvent: false });
```

this way your `valueChange` handler won't be executed infinitely.

**[Fixed Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yWDJWpom01nxgeQHsHlq?p=preview)**